# Obtener máxima calidad (Full HD) en cámara DSLR conectada a un PC

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo obtener mayor calidad de una cámara DSLR conectada a un PC con JavaScript?

El siguiente código lo encontré en la web y me funciona perfectamente, pero el tamaño máximo de calidad que obtengo es de 1280x720 (HD Ready) y me gustaría poder obtener por lo menos 1920x1080 (Full HD).

He estado investigando y he entendido que depende del navegador, que le puedes poner un "ideal", pero que no es seguro que lo alcance u obtengas.

Éste es el código que uso:

```
 var console = { log: msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>" };

 (async () => {
 try {
 let constraints = {video: {width: 9999}};
 video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
 let track = video.srcObject.getTracks()[0];
 if (track.getSettings) {
 let {width, height, frameRate} = track.getSettings();
 console.log(`${width}x${height}x${frameRate}`);
 }
 await new Promise(resolve => video.onloadedmetadata = resolve);
 console.log(`${video.videoWidth}x${video.videoHeight}`);
 } catch(e) {
 console.log(e);
 }
 })();
```

Comment: Por el código imagino que estás obteniendo una fuente de vídeo de la cámara del móvil en el navegador. ¿Has probado con el parámetro `ideal` en `constraints.video`? Además, ¿necesitas sacar la instantánea en ese momento mientras miras la previsualización o te vale con solicitar al navegador que el usuario te saque una foto a máxima calidad con su cámara? Lo digo porque la fuente de vídeo tiene limitaciones en resolución, pero la cámara como método de obtención de medios puede entregarte la foto a la mayor resolución que soporta el móvil.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿vas a usar este código en una DSLR real o un móvil?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Deseo obtener la mayor (mejor) resolución y lo realizo desde mi computadora (en el navegador). Cuento con una cámara DSLR.

Comment: Entonces la respuesta que estaba redactando no sirve, ya que solo es válido para dispositivos móviles. Échale un vistazo de todas maneras, pero el problema es que está limitado por la fuente de vídeo.

Comment: Disculpa Abner. ¿Tu cámara DSLR soporta comportarse como una webcam 1080p a través de USB? ¿Estás usando HDMI y una capturadora? Estoy probando con la webcam del móvil y obtengo 1080p. Mira ese ejemplo: https://ojgarciab.github.io/webcam-test/ y el código en el repositorio: https://github.com/ojgarciab/webcam-test/blob/master/index.html y mira esta captura: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPUVY.jpg

Comment: @OscarGarcia Estoy usando HDMI y una capturadora, probaré subiendo un html al servidor para testearlo desde el Móvil. Probé en ojgarciab.github.io/webcam-test y obtuve 1280 x 720 con la cámara web de mi Computadora, en unos momentos lo haré con la DSLR y la capturadora. Mil gracias. Comprendo perfectamente tu ejemplo y que el resultado está en 1920 x 1080. Agradezco mucho tu conocimiento.

Comment: ¿Puedes probar a abrir la aplicación de Cámara de Windows y mirar en su configuración las resoluciones que soporta tu capturadora? Así nos aseguramos que no sea un problema de resolución máxima de la capturadora. Puedes ver un ejemplo con las resoluciones de la cámara de mi ordenador (el máximo que da es 720p): https://i.stack.imgur.com/44bQC.jpg

Comment: @OscarGarcia Estoy trabajando con una Mac, el día de mañana haré las pruebas con una PC y también quiero realizar pruebas desde un móvil, revisar su calidad. Lo único que deseo es trabajar una imagen en "alta calidad" en un canvas, tal vez optare por capturar la fotografía en mi DSLR y después enviarla a mi computadora para así hacer el proceso en un canvas. Mil gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar capturas con la cámara a través de la cámara delantera o trasera de un móvil deberías hacer uso del atributo [`capture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture) de las etiquetas `<input>` como te muestro a continuación:

```css
input[capture] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button><label for="delantera"> delantera</label></button>
  <input type="file" id="delantera"
    accept="image/*" capture="user"
  />
</div>
<div>
  <button><label for="trasera"> trasera</label></button>
  <input type="file" id="trasera"
    accept="image/*" capture="environment"
  />
</div>
```

PD: Redactando el final de esta respuesta el OP deja un comentario indicando que usa un dispositivo de sobremesa y no uno móvil, por lo que esta respuesta no se ajusta a lo que busca. Redactando explicación de alternativas.